# How to access class of a spring-integration project?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a project based on spring-integration . I want to use some of its class in other project ,i added reference to spring-integration based project class in other project all `autowired` object become null , as i am using new operator to create the object , how can i access the object using `applicationContext` from other project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't autowire beans that you create yourself (with `new`); you have to add them to a spring application context. Perhaps if you show your configuration and what you are trying to do, someone can help.